# Ormlite in a IntentService

Tags: android, ormlite, intentservice

I'm working with OrmLite but I get an exception when I'm trying to use it into a IntentService:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: fr.solutis.solutis, PID: 29456
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service fr.solutis.solutis.notifications.NotificationDemandeService:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1513)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)
>                         at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.openFileId(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:310)
>                         at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:76)
>                         at fr.solutis.solutis.helpers.DatabaseHelper.(DatabaseHelper.java:56)
>                         at fr.solutis.solutis.notifications.NotificationDemandeService.(NotificationDemandeService.java:25)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3145)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1513) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

code:

```
public class NotificationDemandeService extends IntentService {
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(NotificationDemandeService.this);
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    Boolean isUrlAvailable = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    String message = "";

    public NotificationDemandeService() {
        super("EnvoieService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {

            List<Demandes> demandes = db.getAllDemandesRenvoie();
...

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just by calling:

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

after:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```

Gonna work, I don't understand the issue, but it works !